# C++ 11 operator overload with return type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype, type-deduction

I have a template class that depends on one type (for example `template <typename T> class Vector`). Now, I want to overload the arithmetic operators such that:

- I can use them with Vectors instantiated with two different types;
- The result is deduced in the same way of the template instance types;

Example:

```
Vector<float> fv = {1.5, 2.5};
Vector<int> iv = {1,2};
auto s1 = fv + iv;   // s1 MUST be of type Vector<float> == {2.5, 4.5}
auto s2 = iv + fv;   // s2 MUST be of type Vector<float> == {2.5, 4.5}
```

I think that, in a generic purpose mathematical library that implements Matrices, Vectors, Polynomials, etc., this would be a feature that makes the difference in terms of usability.

I found three ways to obtain this result with C++11

1. `->` notation

   ```
   template <typename T, typename U>
   auto operator +(const Vector<T> &lhs, const Vector<U> &rhs)
       -> Vector<decltype(lhs[0]+rhs[0])>
   {
       Vector<decltype(lhs[0]+rhs[0])> res(lhs);
       res += rhs;
       return res;
   }
   ```
2. `declval`

   ```
   template <typename T, typename U> 
   Vector<decltype(std::declval<T>()+std::declval<U>())> 
   operator +(const Vector<T> &lhs, const Vector<U> &rhs)
   {
       Vector<decltype(lhs[0]+rhs[0])> res(lhs);
       res += rhs;
       return res;
   }
   ```
3. `declval` as default type arg

   ```
   template <typename T, typename U, 
             typename R = decltype(std::declval<T>()+std::declval<U>())> 
   Vector<R> operator +(const Vector<T> &lhs, const Vector<U> &rhs)
   {
       Vector<R> res(lhs);
       res += rhs;
       return res;
   }
   ```

What, in your opinion, the best approach to implement such a feature?
If is there a FOURTH better solution I'll appreciate it.

Do you consider such "interworking" operators a worthwhile feature?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Davide

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but use `return res;`, not `return std::move(res);`. The former allows [NRVO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), and if NRVO isn't getting used for whatever reason, it'll still implicitly move, never copy.

Comment: Also, surely `std::move` returns `Vector<T>&&`, but your return type is declared as `Vector<T>`?

Comment: @Eric No, that part is right. Returning `Vector<T>&&` would mean returning a reference to a function-local object that can no longer be used after the function has returned.

Comment: With evil specialization of `Vector<T>`, The 2 computed types may differ in snippet 2. A third method to compute type would be `std::common_type<T, U>`

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not such operators are a "good idea" depends on your use-cases. But if you want to implement them, I suggest you use a traits class, derived from `std::common_type`, to gain more control:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct VectorCommonType : std::common_type<T,U> {};

template<typename T, typename U>
using VectorCommonTypeT = Vector<typename VectorCommonType<T,U>::type>;
```

That way you (or the user of the class) can specialize it when needed. Use it like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
VectorCommonTypeT<T,U> operator+(const Vector<T> &lhs, const Vector<U> &rhs)
{
    VectorCommonTypeT<T,U> res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: There are cases where such a feature is considerare a bad idea or bad design?

Comment: @Davide Yes, those cases exist. For example if you simply don't want accidental mixing of types. It might lead to more instantiations (of both `Vector` and other classes), which might lead to code-bloat, trashing the instruction-cache, etc. In an embedded environment, this might be a real problem. *Not* having above operators might help to catch those at compile-time.

Comment: What purpose does VectorCommonType serve here? Why create a no-op subclass of std::common_type?

Comment: @Eric As I said, it allows you to add specializations when needed. Without it, you'd have to specialize `std::common_type`, but that might also be used for other purposes and hence you won't have the limited scope of `Vector`.